# bmw 323i not starting

Tags: starting, bmw

is there a special hidden reset switch or button in a 2001 bmw 323i to get the car to turn over and start after having the negative cable disconnected then reconnected? The most it does is 3 clicks everytime.

Comment: Why did you disconnect the battery?  What else was wrong?

Comment: The battery is healthy and charged?

Answer (score 1):

I had a 2003 325i and disconnected the battery many times with no issues afterwards, make sure the battery is charged and connections are clean and tight.